# TypeORM save function seems to generate individual insert statements instead of one bulk insert SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, typeorm, planetscale

I am using TypeORM as the ORM for my PlanetScale (MySQL) DB. I want to insert records in bulk. My code looks like this:

```js
const batch = [{name: 'a'},{name: 'b'},{name: 'c'},{name: 'd'},{name: 'e'}];

// generate IDs
const insertData = nameRepository.create(batch);

// bulk insert
await nameRepository.save(insertData);
```

It generates sql that looks like this (5 individual queries in one transaction):

```sql
insert into name (id, name) values (1, 'a');
insert into name (id, name) values (2, 'b');
insert into name (id, name) values (3, 'c');
insert into name (id, name) values (4, 'd');
insert into name (id, name) values (5, 'e');
```

While I expect this to be something like this:

```sql
insert into name (id, name) values 
  (1, 'a'),
  (2, 'b'),
  (3, 'c'),
  (4, 'd'),
  (5, 'e');
```

This wouldn't have been an issue but I am seeing timeout errors and transaction failing ([save gets executed in one single transaction](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/repository-api#:%7E:text=%20it%20saves%20all%20given%20entities%20in%20a%20single%20transaction%20)) and my hunch is this happens due the fact that I am running 100s of inserts per batch creating too many insert request for my hobby plan (smallest possible instance) in PlanetScale.

I can't change `timeout` value in PlanetScale. It's fixed to 20s.

With this info in mind, my question is: How can I force TypeOrm to generate one single bulk insert query?

Thanks!

Comment: I tested the scenario in my own project, which uses TypeORM with PostgreSQL, and it worked correctly for me. To identify if **multiple INSERT** queries are being executed, you can check the PostgreSQL logs or enable logging to capture the queries. Additionally, using TypeORM's query builder can help you construct and execute queries in a more structured manner. You can find more information about the query builder in the [TypeORM documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/insert-query-builder)

Comment: Thanks @MansouriRayen. I am using PlanetScale -- a MySQL variant, but I don't think it affects how the queries are generated. The log that I am seeing in the console looks like multiple individual queries. I think I can use query builder, but that would mean I will have to change like 40 places in the codebase. :)